# Comment Count in Bones

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using [Bones for Wordpress](http://themble.com/bones/).

How would I show a comment count in the article footer on the main index (with a link to the comments on the single post page)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a total site comment count or each particular post has a comment count along with it displayed on the index page? 
Not too sure about the return wp_count_comments(); or the listed wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=bones_comments'); function in the comments.php file. (don't load it directly)

I've used my own in the past:

```
function get_comments_number( $post_id = 0 ) {
    $post_id = absint( $post_id );

    if ( !$post_id )
        $post_id = get_the_ID();

    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if ( ! isset($post->comment_count) )
        $count = 0;
    else
        $count = $post->comment_count;

    return apply_filters('get_comments_number', $count, $post_id);
}
```

Other wise you can add the WP function to your loop to add it to the output of each post with.

```
wp_count_comments( post_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the comments count of a post simply by follow

```
<?php echo $my_var = get_comments_number( $post_id ); ?>
```

you can get it by using inside the loop in your index page

also follow will lead to you the single page of a post

```
 <a class="your-class" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read more</a>
```